# Why grails run-war refuses remote connections?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I want to test something quick in my app so I decided to run grails prod run-war.
I can access my app locally, but I can't connect from another computer.
If i copy war file to my tomcat installation it will run fine and allow remote connections.

I haven't seen any info in docs about this behaviour so... 
Is there any way I could connect remotely to my app when running grails prod run-war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It start listening on `localhost` by default, you can specify IP adress to bind to:

```
$grails -Dserver.host=192.168.1.100 run-war
```

where `192.168.1.100` is requred IP adress

See http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/run-war.html

Comment: I was actually looking at something around security rather than interface binding... thanks a lot!